# How to uniquely identify an HTML element on a page from the content script in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here's my dilemma. My Chrome Extension first needs to scan a web page (that is being injected) from its *content script* and look for `textarea` elements and then at some later iterations be able to identify those elements on the page.

My original assumption was that having an HTML element's `id` and `name` attributes would uniquely identify it on the page, but that turns out not to be the case. I encounter pages (especially with Facebook "Like" button IFrames) that there may be multiple `textarea` elements with no `id` and identical `name`.

So my code:

```
var frmTxa = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
if(frmTxa)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < frmTxa.length; i++)
    {
        objCollect.id = frmTxa[i].id;
        objCollect.name = frmTxa[i].name;

        addCollect.push(objCollect);
    }
}
```

creates duplicates.

So my question, is there an attribute of an HTML element that can uniquely identify it on the page? And if no, how else to do it?

Comment: Why don't you just **add** a new `data-*` attribute, like `data-identifier="whatever"` (or something more specific), so that way you have control over the uniqueness? You'll only need to store that attribute in the `addCollect` array

Comment: @Ian: But how would I know that my data element won't create a conflict with existing attribute on the page?

Comment: If you make its name specific enough, there won't be any conflict. It may be silly, but give it a sort of "namespace" - `data-c00000fd-textarea-id="whatever"` even

Comment: @Ian: OK, good point. But if the page is refreshed in the browser. I won't be able to use my special IDs, will I?

Comment: Ahh I see. Yeah you're right. Basically, the answer to "is there an attribute of an HTML element that can uniquely identify it on the page?" is **no**. So my comment was my idea of getting around that. At the same time, if the page refreshed, any "identifier", other than a static attribute, wouldn't be accurate. For example, if the browser kept an underlying completely unique identifier for an element and exposed it to us, it would change when the page is refreshed (or even if the content in the page is replaced/whatever).

Comment: @Ian: Yeah, that's what I thought. Just curious, will `tabIndex` attribute be set automatically?

Comment: Or will `getElementsByTagName` return elements in the exact same order? In that case I can rely on the element's index in the array it fetches back.

Comment: What about saving the XPath to the element? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_XPath

Comment: @c00000fd I'm not sure what you mean about `tabIndex` set automatically - there is no default value, so if it's not set, it doesn't have a `tabIndex`. Also, as long as the elements are in the DOM in the same order, `getElementsByTagName` will return them in the same order. The comment above, about XPath, could be helpful